# How to fix awkward text in columns?

Tags: css, text

I've been practicing with columns lately and I just can't seem to get them right.

[image]

This is probably very simple to fix, but I'm pretty bad at web development at the moment. The highlighted section in the picture would obviously look better if it began at the top of the second column, how can I bump it over?

I never know exactly what code to post, so please tell me what you need to see and I'll edit it in as fast as I can.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: If your text and the container height and width are static, you might just add `<br/>` in the text.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I didn't try that first. Jesus Christ. Thank you! I obviously have to practice some more...

Comment: and then you'll have a line in your next column. Just do it right.

Comment: this is the major problem when using `multi-column`

Comment: You should post a sample of your markup (even if it’s just `p` elements, it’s important to know that it is) and specify *how* the text should be formatted or, negatively speaking, which types of breaks should be disallowed.

Answer (score 1):

The `break-inside: avoid-column` on paragraphs should do the trick, but the browser support is not great. You can try also `-webkit-column-break-inside:avoid` and `page-break-inside:avoid`  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wzxsogzb/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="test">
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi sed turpis congue, dignissim nibh eu, ullamcorper neque. Etiam id mi cursus, pellentesque sapien at, volutpat ligula. Sed mattis dapibus dictum. Duis hendrerit ut est in rutrum. Suspendisse in nibh fringilla, congue erat non, euismod eros. Proin at elit ac dolor pharetra gravida quis in quam. Sed fringilla porta quam non tincidunt.
</p>
<p>
Phasellus eget purus et tellus lacinia faucibus non nec massa. Duis mattis vestibulum sagittis. Sed dapibus efficitur velit, vitae lobortis tortor cursus vel. Maecenas eu elementum enim. Nunc porttitor eleifend enim, sit amet dapibus enim hendrerit in. Quisque congue urna ut nulla placerat, ac pretium nisl elementum. Aliquam nec tristique diam. Quisque eget fringilla purus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Mauris orci arcu, porta sed ligula vitae, lobortis dignissim massa. Aliquam suscipit finibus augue non tincidunt. Aenean fringilla nulla eget urna ultricies, in imperdiet orci mollis. Pellentesque sit amet mattis ligula, vitae laoreet ex. Mauris molestie sodales condimentum. Vestibulum tortor dolor, scelerisque non molestie nec, mollis eget sapien. Suspendisse commodo magna a est elementum, a faucibus nisl sagittis.
</p>
<p>
Proin facilisis non turpis a consequat. Duis a mi dapibus, tempor velit condimentum, aliquet quam. Ut ut sapien vestibulum orci egestas facilisis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Etiam porttitor libero mattis justo finibus, a mattis erat ullamcorper. Donec et ultrices metus, vestibulum dictum est. Sed bibendum sodales egestas. Duis molestie libero at tortor sagittis, sed pellentesque dolor gravida. Pellentesque metus ipsum, varius at gravida ac, maximus id urna. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
</p>
<p>
Morbi gravida imperdiet mauris, id dictum quam congue in. Integer purus justo, pellentesque vestibulum euismod in, finibus ut neque. Sed imperdiet iaculis blandit. Mauris gravida, nibh quis placerat fringilla, nisl nibh tincidunt neque, et tincidunt dolor ex rutrum quam. In non tellus arcu. Sed feugiat nibh ac lectus volutpat, sed varius augue lobortis. Nullam velit magna, laoreet id egestas vitae, luctus et leo. Fusce ultricies dolor blandit nibh pulvinar, vel maximus augue rhoncus. Curabitur posuere, libero nec mollis eleifend, orci sapien sodales mi, non fringilla sem ligula non leo.
</p>
<p>
Maecenas id lobortis nulla. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Fusce mattis tortor ut enim laoreet, blandit dignissim augue sodales. Duis a est diam. Phasellus lobortis aliquam tellus. Sed sit amet elit pulvinar, volutpat dui sit amet, tempus dolor. Nam quis feugiat metus. Quisque dictum dui at sapien pulvinar tincidunt. Aliquam at ornare diam. Nam interdum lobortis urna ac aliquet. Integer in sollicitudin metus. Sed rutrum, dolor non venenatis malesuada, velit enim pulvinar dui, ac sagittis massa ante et arcu. Nullam arcu odio, varius porttitor aliquam congue, lobortis at nibh.
</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.test {
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3;

    -webkit-column-gap: 40px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-gap: 40px; /* Firefox */
    column-gap: 40px;
}
.test p{display:inline-block}
```

Here you can see how text breaks ONLY in paragraphs and nothing else. No need for dirty hacks, br or stuff like that. [See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdy3n791/)

Comment: Breaking *only* between paragraphs isn’t what was asked, and it surely isn’t normal or good typesetting practice.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela He said - "Wow I can't believe I didn't try that first. Jesus Christ. Thank you! I obviously have to practice some more..." for "Breaking only between paragraphs" :)

Comment: What matters as SO is what the question actually asks for and how an answer addresses that.

Comment: it's what he asked (in other words) and it works flawlessly. Also, what matters is to use correct markup, if he doesn't know it, it's good to tell him. The fact that you're nitpicking on everything, even correct answers, doesn't make you more right. It just makes you nitpicking, for lack of better word.